# Escape special options in CMake

Tags: cmake

CMake use named arguments, but how to specify an argument which value is exactly the same as the name of the argument?

Example:

```
set(msg "COMMAND")
add_custom_command(TARGET tgt COMMAND echo ${msg})
```

will not work because `${msg}` is interpreted as the name of the option, not the argument of the command `echo`. So it will execute `echo` without any argument.

Output: `command ECHO activated.` (on Windows)

Wanted output: `COMMAND`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CMake use named arguments

CMake does *not* use named arguments! It has argument lists and the command-specific "keywords" are merely delimiters for sublists of arguments.

For this specific command, you can use an always-true generator expression to "escape" it:

```
set(msg COMMAND)
add_custom_command(
  TARGET tgt
  COMMAND echo "$<1:${msg}>"
)
```

This works because the arguments are matched immediately during configure time (and `$<1:COMMAND>` is not the same as `COMMAND`), while the generator expression will be evaluated later, at generation time.